# jQAssistant: org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ClientException: Unable to convert [C to Neo4j Value - known error?

Tags: neo4j, jqassistant

I'm starting with jQAssist scanning (version 1.9.1). Most of the Maven projects can be scanned without problem, but there is a problem with some tests.

I get this stack trace:

```
[WARNING] Cannot scan class '/foo/bar/util/validation/constraints/VerfahrensspracheTest$Geschaeft.class'.
org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ClientException: Unable to convert [C to Neo4j Value.
    at org.neo4j.driver.Values.value (Values.java:134)
    at org.neo4j.driver.Values.value (Values.java:297)
    at org.neo4j.driver.Values.value (Values.java:119)
    at org.neo4j.driver.Values.parameters (Values.java:401)
    at com.buschmais.xo.neo4j.remote.impl.datastore.AbstractRemoteDatastorePropertyManager.flush (AbstractRemoteDatastorePropertyManager.java:68)
    at com.buschmais.xo.neo4j.remote.impl.datastore.RemoteDatastoreEntityManager.flush (RemoteDatastoreEntityManager.java:235)
    at com.buschmais.xo.impl.cache.CacheSynchronizationService.flush (CacheSynchronizationService.java:50)
    at com.buschmais.xo.impl.cache.CacheSynchronizationService.flush (CacheSynchronizationService.java:34)
    at com.buschmais.xo.impl.query.XOQueryImpl.flush (XOQueryImpl.java:158)
    at com.buschmais.xo.impl.query.XOQueryImpl.execute (XOQueryImpl.java:138)
```

etc. etc.

The test in question contains an inner class:

```
public class VerfahrensspracheTest extends BeanValidationTestBase<VerfahrensspracheTest.Geschaeft> {

  /**
   * Tests {@link Verfahrenssprache} with English.
   */
  @Test
  public void testEnglish() {
    // Some test
  }

  /**
   * Some bean for testing.
   */
  @SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
  static class Geschaeft extends PrettyPrintObject {

    /**
     * Creates this with valid values.
     */
    public Geschaeft() {
      this.sprache1 = foo.bar.util.type.language.Verfahrenssprache.DEUTSCH;
      this.sprache2 = foo.bar.util.type.language.Verfahrenssprache.ENGLISCH.getISOCode();

      this.sprache3 = Maps.newHashMap();
      this.sprache3.put(foo.bar.util.type.language.Verfahrenssprache.DEUTSCH, "Deutsch");
      this.sprache3.put(foo.bar.util.type.language.Verfahrenssprache.FRANZOESISCH, "Français");
      this.sprache3.put(foo.bar.util.type.language.Verfahrenssprache.ITALIENISCH, "Italiano");
    }

    @Verfahrenssprache
    public foo.bar.util.type.language.Verfahrenssprache sprache1;

    @Verfahrenssprache(englishAllowed = true)
    public String sprache2;

    @Verfahrenssprache
    public Map<foo.bar.util.type.language.Verfahrenssprache, String> sprache3;
  }
}
```

Is there a problem with my inner class or is there a problem with jQAssistant?

Comment: This very likely looks like a bug in jQAssistant or the underlying mapping framework eXtended Objects if a standalone Neo4j server is used. Can you raise an issue with the example above in https://github.com/jQAssistant/jqa-core-framework/? Does this happen as well with the (default) embedded database?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the quick reply. I tried using the embedded database, and that works. So I will raise an issue in GitHub describing the environment better. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, this is the bug: https://github.com/jQAssistant/jqa-core-framework/issues/60

Comment: Thanks, already received a notification. Hopefully it's not a big thing.

Comment: The issue is fixed an will be available with the next release (1.11.0)